# .htaccess not working apache-tomcat

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, mod-jk

I have a apache tomcat server integrated with mod_jk. I have created .htaccess files in the directories I want to restrict. but the problem is .htaccess is working in apache served directories but not in the directories which is served by tomcat.

Apache document root is /var/ww/html
I created a test directory under it and its working fine.

But in  /usr/local/src/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/examples
I created a .htaccess and its not working.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`.htaccess` are Apache Web Server files, not Tomcat. Tomcat just ignore these files. If you serve your application through mod_jk, then anything that `JkMount` maps to is served by Tomcat and no .htaccess will be processed.
If you need to password protect Tomcat directories, you need to create a Realm in Tomcat and protect the web-resource.
An old but I think still accurate [example](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/07/24/tomcat.html)