# leverage browser caching and .htaccess file

Tags: java, .htaccess, tomcat, browser-cache

Where i will find the .htaccess file in tomcat(on windows) in order to **leverage browser caching**? Many blog posts says it will be in root directory of your web application. For example if my application is named as  **myapp** then .htaccess file should be under directory **myapp**. But i am not finding any such file under myapp directory.

Comment: You might have to create that file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Apache Tomcat is **not** Apache HTTP Server. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528552/htaccess-not-working-apache-tomcat

Comment: @home: then can u (or anyone)please explain how to leverage browser caching with tomcat (on windows)?

Comment: AFAIK, you have to build it into your application as Tomcat does not provide sophisticated caching strategies. Your second option is to place a reverse proxy (e.g. Apache HTTP Server) in front of you application server. What is your definition of browser caching?