# block unknown IP Addresses for Apache tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

How can i restrict unknown IP addresses for accessing my apache tomcat server.(Allow only one ip address and restrict all requests from other ip addresses)?

Comment: Does it have to be done with Tomcat? If it's a linux host I would look at something like IP tables.

Comment: I want to restrict it through tomcat server.How can i restrict through tomcat config files?

Answer (score 3):

To block special IP addresses you can put the following in a .htaccess file located in your directory, For Apache Server

```
order allow,deny
allow from 10.20.30.40
deny from All
```

For Tomcat Server

```
<Context path="/path/to/secret_files" ...>
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
allow="127.0.0.1" deny=""/>
</Context>
```

Reference link http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html?page=2

Comment: The user is asking about Tomcat, not Apache httpd. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528552/htaccess-not-working-apache-tomcat

Comment: Check the reference link for Tomcat server http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html?page=2

Comment: for Tomcat server i put the given configuration in which file? Is it conf/context.xml or server.xml file?

Comment: My Tomcat version is 7.0.52, In <Context path="/path/to/secret_files" ...> what is here /path /to, secret_files ?

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html check the reference link